# How do I store game scores including team names for a basketball score counter app?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to store game scores including the team names and date when it was stored from my basketball game counter app when clicking a save button.

Here is the Java code:

```java
package com.example.android.courtcounter;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int scoreTeamA = 0;
int scoreTeamB = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        displayForTeamA(0);
        displayForTeamB(0);
        setTitle("Basketball Count");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You can change team names and scores manually by clicking on them", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    // +3 Points for Team A
    public void addThreeForTeamA (View view) {
        scoreTeamA = scoreTeamA + 3;
        displayForTeamA(scoreTeamA);
    }

    // +2 Points for Team A
    public void addTwoForTeamA (View view) {
        scoreTeamA = scoreTeamA + 2;
        displayForTeamA(scoreTeamA);
    }

    // +1 Point for Team A
    public void addOneForTeamA (View view) {
        scoreTeamA = scoreTeamA +1;
        displayForTeamA(scoreTeamA);
    }

    // Displays the given score for Team A.

    public void displayForTeamA(int score) {
        TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team_a_score);
        scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
    }

    // +3 Points for Team B
    public void addThreeForTeamB (View view) {
        scoreTeamB = scoreTeamB + 3;
        displayForTeamB(scoreTeamB);
    }

    // +2 Points for Team B
    public void addTwoForTeamB (View view) {
        scoreTeamB = scoreTeamB + 2;
        displayForTeamB(scoreTeamB);
    }

    // +1 Point for Team B
    public void addOneForTeamB (View view) {
        scoreTeamB = scoreTeamB +1;
        displayForTeamB(scoreTeamB);
    }

    // Displays the given score for Team B.

    public void displayForTeamB(int score) {
        TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team_b_score);
        scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
    }

    public void resetScore (View view) {
        scoreTeamA = 0;
        scoreTeamB = 0;
        displayForTeamA(scoreTeamA);
        displayForTeamB(scoreTeamB);
    }
}
```

I've stored the scores and team names in EditText views and want to save them and load them later. Anyone got an idea what to use for saving and loading a specific game score?

Comment: Use ```SQLite database``` to store scores.

Comment: @SanketMakani A database would be overkill for this purpose. `SharedPreferences` is much easier to use and covers OP's use case just fine.

Comment: @OP you need to specify the depth of the data you are trying to collect. Without that, its hard to say what you're going to do, please look at my above comment and if that aligns with what you're trying to do, please update your post. Understand your data and its use before trying to collect it. And also returning the sum of the score of a team is as easy as querying the db for all scores for a team (within some limits) and then returning that value.

Answer (score 1):

I recognize this code from Udacity's excellent "Intro to Android" course .. You'd have to use `sharedPreferences` to save the scores. For example:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(
                getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt("scoreTeamA", scoreTeamA);
editor.putInt("scoreTeamB", scoreTeamB);
editor.apply();
```

And then to retrieve the values:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(
                getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int scoreTeamA = sharedPref.getInt(scoreTeamA, 0);
int scoreTeamB = sharedPref.getInt(scoreTeamB, 0);
```

Comment: This is all you need, sharedPreferences don't go away between runs of the app. They'll only disappear if you uninstall the app.

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll try to implement it like this

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a database for all users around the world, you should use SQL and maybe php programming languages. SQL for database editting, php for controlling the database edittings.

But if you just want to store the data just for the device you are using the app on then you can simply create a text file in the android project file. Then you can fill the text file in the way you want using code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use databases but I think it is more than what you need.
You could also use files:

1. Add these at your manifest.xml:

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   ```
2. Add two functions:

   ```
   void writeToFile(String string) {
       FileOutputStream outputStream = openFileOutput("thiswillbethenameofyourfile", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
       outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
       outputStream.close();
   } 

   String readFromFile() {
       String content;
       FileInputStream inputStream = openFileInput("thiswillbethenameofyourfile");
       byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
       int n;
       while ((n = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
       {
            content.append(new String(buffer, 0, n));
       }
       return content;
   }
   ```
3. Call WriteToFile with a string that contains the score.
4. Call readFromFile to get that score back.
5. You can use multiple files to store multiple data right if you should store every thing in one file but this is a good start!

Also as @Andrew Sun mentioned you could use sharedPreferences

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html